# subtracting Stings from an array of Strings in the initializer using core-data?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, core-data

I need to mutate the library using the stored Array. This works:

```
var library = ["Monday", "Tuesday","wednesday", "Thursday"]

var libraryOff = ["Monday","wednesday"]

library = Array(Set(library).subtracting(libraryOff))

print(library) //=>["Tuesday", "Thursday"]
```

But, I need it to work using something like,

```
var library = ["Monday", "Tuesday","wednesday", "Thursday"]

var libraryOff = [newLibrary]

library = Array(Set(library).subtracting(libraryOff))
```

`newLibrary` being coreData that when printed reads, "monday, wednesday",

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: `var libraryOff = newLibrary.components(separatedBy: ",")`? Is that what you are looking for? Careful though with the spaces, might need to trim them.

Comment: The trouble seems to either be with the way I have my core data set up or because ```var library``` is in the initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Array-Set-Array* dance is ugly, there is a much more efficient way

```
var library = ["Monday", "Tuesday","wednesday", "Thursday"]
let libraryOff = ["Monday","wednesday"] // Why is wednesday lowercased?

library.removeAll{ libraryOff.contains($0) }
```

To use a comma separated string you have to split the string and remove possible leading and trailing whitespace characters

```
var library = ["Monday", "Tuesday","wednesday", "Thursday"]
let libraryOff =  "Monday, wednesday"
let trimmedLibraryOff = libraryOff.split(separator: ",").map{$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}

library.removeAll{ trimmedLibraryOff.contains($0) }
```